# Connecting RCA audio cables to Arduino

Tags: audio, wires, sound, speaker

I'm working on a project which needs better audio quality than just a piezo buzzer, so I went out and bought a pair of used cheap speakers for $3. It turns out that they have RCA audio inputs rather than 3.5mm inputs. There is a separated left and right speaker, with a left and right RCA audio wire coming out of each.

I've looked around on the internet about connecting speakers to Arduino, but I've only found ways to connect 3.5mm/TRRS to Arduino, or the RCA video jack to Arduino, but not the RCA audio.

How should I go about wiring the RCA audio wires to my Arduino Uno so that I can play basic melodies off it? Are any amplifier circuits, voltage dividers, etc. needed?

I am okay with splicing the cables.

Thanks

Comment: lookup "rca to headphone pinout" and pretend you have headphones. they are the same once you cut the connector off anyway (given one extra common with RCA)

Comment: I am trying to connect male RCA cables (which come on the speaker) to the Arduino, not the headphone jack

Comment: ahh. if it's on the speaker itself, you need some type of amplifier circuit; the arduino can only pump out a few dozen millwatts. get an amp that has RCA speaker-level outputs.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Can I build this amp or do I have to buy one? How would I connect the RCA cable to the amplifier (what are the individual wires inside the RCA cable)?